# Getting negative numbers or zero as output of factorial in C

Tags: c, factorial

I've written a very simple program which calculate the factorial of a number, the problem is that from 30 to 60 approximately, it returns a negative number and from 70 it returns 0. 
I don't what I've done wrong. Could this problem depend on the computing power of my computer?
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int x, i;
long long int f = 1;

printf("Insert a number:");
scanf("%d", &x);

    if (x == 0){
        printf("0! = 1");
     }
    else { 
        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
            f *= i;
        }
        printf("%d! è = %lli", x, f);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change f to long long unsigned int, in large numbers the msb will be 1 which represents negative numbers

Comment: It's not the computing power of your computer, but rather the range of a long long int, which just isn't sufficient to represent anything even remotely close to 70!. A long long int is usually 64Bit, which means the largest number representable will be 2^63

Comment: @sergeyrar That "fixes" the negative numbers, but the results will still be incorrect (just less obvious). The highest factorial still representable with 64Bit is 20! by the way, anything higher than that and the regular integer types just won't cut it anymore

Comment: So is there no way I can calculate 70! with a C program?

Comment: @Schiele there is, but you can't use the normal integer types and operators anymore. Essentially you'll have to do the multiplications as you would do them on paper, and store the numbers as integer arrays. There are however many libraries already available which do exactly that, just google "bignum" or "bigint"

Comment: `20!` is the largest factorial that will fit into a `long long`, assuming `long long` is 64 bits. To calculate `70!` with a C program, you need to implement `f` as an array, and write your own multiplication routine. According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), `70!` has 101 digits. So an array of 101 bytes where each byte represents one digit should do the trick.

Comment: @FelixG Should I just include that library without modify the rest of the code?

Comment: @Schiele no, those libraries (like gmp for example) provide a set of functions and datatypes you have to use. So instead of doing `f *= i` you'll have to use some kind of multiplication function provided by the library. That being said, implementing a basic bigint function yourself (like addition or multiplication) is not all that hard and you could learn a lot along the way. You'll have to ask yourself if you just want a solution asap, or take the opportunity to learn more about bigints in general.

Comment: Hi, You can not do this like you are doing, please go through this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/ , and try by your self . if after this you stuck anywhere then ask again.

Comment: Thank you so much to everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void Carry(int bit[],int pos)
{
    int i,carray=0;
    for(i=0;i<=pos;i++)
    {
        bit[i]+=carray;
        if(bit[i]<=9) 
        {
            carray=0;
        }
        else if(bit[i]>9&&i<pos)
        {
            carray=bit[i]/10;
            bit[i]%=10;     
        }
        else if(bit[i]>9&&i>=pos)
        {
            while(bit[i]>9) 
            {
                carray=bit[i]/10;  
                bit[i]%=10;       
                i++;
                bit[i]=carray;   
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int num,pos,digit,i,j,m,n;
    double sum=0; 
    int *fact;   
    printf("input want to calculute  factorial num:");
    scanf("%d",&num);       
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        sum+=log10(i);
    }
    digit=(int)sum+1;  
    if(!(fact=(int *)malloc((digit+1)*sizeof(int))))
    {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<=digit;i++)
    {
        fact[i]=0;
    }
    fact[0]=1;
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++)
    {
        for(j=digit;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(fact[j]!=0)
            {
                pos=j;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<=pos;j++)
        {
            fact[j]*=i; 
        }
        Carry(fact,pos); 
    }
    for(j=digit;j>=0;j--)
    {
        if(fact[j]!=0)
        {
                pos=j; 
                break;
        }
    }
    m=0; 
    n=0;  
    for(i=pos;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d",fact[i]);
        m++;
        if(m%4==0)  
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if(m==40)  
        {
            printf("\n");
            m=0;
            n++;
            if(n==10)
            {
                printf("\n");
                n=0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```